# CLI vs API calls from C++ program

Tags: c++, linux

I am new to Linux development Environment and I am trying to create a C++ component for my app which will help to change timezone on Linux machine using systemd sdbus interface.

In one solution I wrote a code that is using sdbus interface `org.freedesktop.timedate1` to change timezone. And on another solution, I am simply calling `execvp` on `timedatectl` and arguments as `Set-timezone` followed by the input to set the system timezone.
Eg.: Which is preciously replicating the following CLI: `sudo timedatectl set-timezone "Africa/Cairo"`.

Both works just fine.

Since, calling CLI is pretty straight forward from C++, then using API which is adding some extra lines of code to the code base, I am preferring CLI call over API.

Question:
What could be the downsides of using CLI commands over API calls (not just for this example but) in general?

Comment: Command line programs primarily report error details with _human-readable text_, which can be very tricky for another program to interpret.

Comment: 1) Anyone could change the behavior of your program by replacing the process expected to exist on the target machine.

Comment: Spinning up and then waiting on termination of another process can be more time consuming than an API call in the same process.

Comment: What if your user is not configured as a superuser and sudo fails?

Comment: This is an excellent question that I've had myself. Have you found an answer yet?